# Hibernate query last to long

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, hql

I would like to ask you for some help. I have a code in hibernate that is:

```
public PartnerBean getPartner(String uniqueNumber) {

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

    String username= getUser().getUsername();

    query.append(" select '" + username + "' as audituser, {pp.*} from tblpartner pp ");
    query.append(" WHERE pp.uniqueNumber = ").append(uniqueNumber);

    SQLQuery sqlQuery = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query.toString());
    sqlQuery.addEntity("pp", PartnerBean.class);

    List<PartnerBean> results = sqlQuery.list(); 

    if (results != null && results.size() > 0)
       return (PartnerBean) results.get(0);
    else
       return null;
}
```

But it lasts over 3 sec and that is to much. I need it to be faster but to retain this part: `select '" + username + "' as audituser` in the query because there is audit under the `tblpartner` table and it has to show the complete query with the person who is loged into the app (username). So I need select as it is, but faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an index on the field uniqueNumber.